# Updating a value via a FaunaDB query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, faunadb

I have a `ReactJS` `NextJS` `web-app`. The following code outputs the correct values to the `terminal` however it fails to update the `database` at all. As such, I think that the [faunaDB](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/crud.html?lang=javascript) `Update` function is incorrectly specified. All `4` `console.log` calls are outputting the correct values.

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");

// your secret hash
const secret = process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET_KEY;
const q = faunadb.query;
const client = new faunadb.Client({ secret });

console.log("CALLLED API")

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;
  console.log("API CALL");
  try {
    const dbs = await client.query(
      console.log("API UPDATE"),
      console.log(formData.likes[0].data.like + 1),

      q.Update(
        q.Ref(q.Collection('Likes'), '__likes_reference__'),
        {
          data: {
            like: formData.likes[0].data.like + 1,
          },
        }
      )
    );
    // ok
    res.status(200).json(dbs.data);
  } catch (e) {
    // something went wrong
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
};
```

## How can I increment the value for `likes` in the database?

Comment: Add the output of the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increment the value for `likes` by `1` with the following code:

```
q.Update(
            q.Ref(q.Collection('Likes'), '__likes_reference__'),
                {
                    data: {
                        like: q.Add(
                            q.Select(
                                ['data', 'like'],
                                q.Get(
                                    q.Ref(
                                        q.Collection('Likes'),
                                        '__likes_reference__'
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            1
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
```

Comment: Reading the value and incrementing it inside of a single transaction is a good way to avoid race conditions caused by requests from the client side. 

Did swapping in this code fix your issue?  Can you mark this answer as solved, then?

Answer (score 0):

Is this is your reference id '**likes_reference**' your some random generated number.  If that number is present then use it to get the reference of the document from the collection and you can add the output to the question for more understanding

```
  like: (formData.likes[0].data.like + 1),
```

You can surround the like count with brackets and try also